# Broken Pipe Python

Tags: python

trying to create a simple TCP client/server connection using python and when running the python script we are getting an error for a broken pipe, do you see any errors in my code that would cause this error to show itself, thanks:)

Client Code

```
import socket
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ip = "HIDDEN"
print ip
port = HIDDEN
address = (ip, port)
client.connect(address)
client.send("HELLO")
client.recv(2048)
print client.recv(2048)
```

Server Code

```
import socket
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

IP = "HIDDEN"
PORT = HIDDEN
ADDRESS = (IP, PORT)


server.bind(ADDRESS)
server.listen(1)

print "Started Listening for connection on IP ", IP, " and port number ",      PORT

client,addr = server.accept()

print "Got connection from IP ", addr[0], "and port ", addr[1]

while True:
        ConnectionInfo = client.recv(2048)
        if(ConnectionInfo =="HELLO"):
                client.send("Hello to you as well")

        elif(ConnectionInfo == "Goodbye"):
                client.send("Goodbye to you as well")
                client.close()
                break
        else:
                client.send("invalid keyword, please try again")


client.close()
server.shutdown()
server.close()
```

Comment: Quick guess: Your second `recv` causes a timeout. Anyway: Where is the "Java"-part?

Comment: wont even lie, didnt mean to write java, thanks for pointing that out to me, i goofed. thanks!

Comment: @jp-jee are you talking about the second recv in the client code?

Comment: yes, you're trying to receive the information twice, you should store it in a variable instead.